# What is the name of the functions inside a DLL?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

How to know what function names are inside a DLL? So that I can use it in in java with [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: If you're trying to access a function in an existing DLL, you may want to consider using JNA rather than JNI. JNA is less work and easier to use than JNI. See https://jna.dev.java.net/.

Comment: wow , thanks. It is really more easy to do it in this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dumpbin.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) with the /EXPORTS switch to list the functions in a DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can read the names and ordinals of the functions exported by a DLL.